# How can I use lodash to filter value between two date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

`created_at` is the value I Want to compare with the `beginDate` and the `endDate`.

```js
var newARRA = chain(this.props.transferts.transfertAccount)
.filter({ 'officeSender':
      this.props.users.user.office,officeReceiver:this.state.selectedOffice,
  'created_at':(this.state.beginDate,this.state.endDate)})
    
.groupBy("currency")
.map((v, k) => ({
     currency: k,
  amount: sumBy(v, 'fee')
 }))
.value();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the [filter's predicate function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#filter). Example (not tested):

```
var newARRA = chain(this.props.transferts.transfertAccount)
  .filter(({ officeSender, officeReceiver, created_at }) => {
    return _.eq(officeSender, this.props.users.user.office) &&
           _.eq(officeReceiver, this.state.selectedOffice) &&
           _.gte(created_at, this.state.beginDate) &&
           _.lte(created_at, this.state.endDate) &&
  })
  .groupBy("currency")
  .map((v, k) => ({
    currency: k,
    amount: sumBy(v, 'fee')
  }))
  .value();
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using a date library. 
>
date-fns could do this for you

```
var isWithinRange = require('date-fns/is_within_range')
isWithinRange(
   new Date(2014, 0, 3), new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 7)
)//=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the moment library to achieve this for you, assuming that the two values are moment like dates:

```
'created_at': moment().isBetween(this.state.beginDate, this.state.endDate)
```

This does assume that the dates are moment-like and don't require any pre-processing by the moment library.

Comment: I cant use Moment since the format of the 'created_at' value have to be pre-process.